# Чем загружать видео?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Для загрузки картинок использую [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), файл сохраняю и обрабатываю в [потоке](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

Сработает ли такое с видео, ведь `multipart/form-data` может быть очень большой и, насколько я понимаю, на `точку вхождения` мне прилетает `buffer` всего файла, а не `chunk`, или я не прав?

Comment: обычное сохранение multer-ом на диск работает через поток https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/storage/disk.js. если тебе прилетает буфер то ты идёшь через другое хранилище?

Comment: У меня у мультера движок написан (c твоей помощью, за что спасибо). А разве `multipart-form data` не все сразу шлет, как тогда прилетает `content-size`?

Comment: я сейчас немного занят, чтоб копнуть глубже, но кмк нам без разницы как клиент-сайд посылает данные, а важно как мы их принимаем. т.е. если наш бэк начинает обработку stream-ом то мы оперируем чанками и можем не заботится о расходе памяти так как за нас это разрулит nginx/node.js.

Comment: Добавь в ответ, закрою.

Comment: если я помогал тебе с multer-ом сделать ресайз или другую манипуляцию с картинкой то твой случай прост: использовать на роуте 2 мултеровских загрузчика и порулить по чему-то вроде контент-тайпа. но это я пишу умозрительно и второпях и, скорее всего, ошибаюсь так как multipart не даст нужной информации. а может даст. нужно смотреть как это всё порулить. а можно порулить и внутри "нашего" кастомного MulterStorage

Comment: "Добавь в ответ, закрою." не, мне скучно писать ответ без кода )